# How to aggregate score by value of manytomany field in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    category = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, max_length=50)
    setting = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

| id | subject_id | contact_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 66 | 13 |
| 2 | 66 | 28 |
| 3 | 71 | 13 |
| 4 | 71 | 28 |
| 5 | 98 | 13 |
| 6 | 98 | 28 |
| 7 | 98 | 37 |
| 8 | 20 | 13 |

The setting field is a manytomany property, and it can have multiple setting values ​​per subject object. The result I want to get is a score by contact_id. The score is calculated as follows.

```
1. 50 points per subject object. 
2. If two people are in charge of a subject, each person gets 25 points, and if three people are in charge of a subject, each person gets 16 (50/3) points.
Desired result: {'contact_id': 13, 'score': 116}, {'contact_id': 28, 'score': 66}, {'contact_id': 37, 'score': 16}




workers = Subject.objects.filter(setting__isnull=False)\
                         .values('id')\
                         .annotate(worker=Count('setting')) 

setting_performance = Subject.objects.filter(setting__isnull=False) \
                            .values('setting')\
                            .annotate(
    setting=Count('id', filter=Q(id__in=workers.filter(worker=1).values('id')), distinct=True) * Value(50),
    collabo_setting=Count('id', filter=Q(id__in=workers.filter(worker__gte=2).values('id')), distinct=True) * Value(50) / workers.filter(id=F('id')).values('worker'),)\
                            .values_list('setting__name', 'setting', 'collabo_setting')
```

The above expression is the code I wrote. It's not correct. Any feedback on django and queryset calculations?

Comment: According to your description I calculated the score of 13 as 116, the score of 28 as 76, and the score of 37 as 16. Am I missing something? For example if I take contact_id 13 into account, it gets 25 point from the subject_id of 66. Because 66 have contact_ids 13 and 28. It gets another 25 points from subject_id 75, and 16 points from 98 and lastly it gets 50 points from subject_id 20. This is how I understand your problem description.

Comment: you're right. The post has been edited. But I want to write code to get 116 points. I haven't been able to solve it all day.